# subprocess.Popen.communicate not effient with large data sets?

Tags: python, linux, shell, bash

I understand communicate() will wait for the process to finish, store data in memory buffer and return. I was thinking the below code will not be efficient as I want to query all interesting rpms and gather information on each one. This will involve ~15 rpms on one server for up to 200 servers in one group.

I want to query the RPM DB in Linux and get information out of every .rpm and store it.

In Linux I would do this:

```
rpm -qa --qf '%{NAME} %{VERSION} %{RELEASE}\n' | grep this
```

and I can use all the --queryformat RPM provides.

So I have this in Python, which works. But I want to make it simple.

```
def getrpms():
queryall = []
rpmqa = subprocess.Popen(['rpm', '-qa'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'stuff'], stdin=rpmqa.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
sort = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-r'], stdin=grep.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
end_of_pipe = sort.stdout

for line in end_of_pipe:
    queryall.append(line.strip())
return queryall

def rpminfo():
for rpm in getrpms():
    command = "rpm -qi {} ".format(rpm)
    args = shlex.split(command)
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    pl = p.communicate()    # returns a tuple
    print pl
```

How can I make this efficient? I saw that I could use Threads and streams but I don't know how.

Comment: RPM has a programming API with Python bindings, described here: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-rpm-programming-python.html. Maybe native integration is better than shell script plumbing and screen scraping?

Comment: I did make a nice script that used that, unfortunately I am using 2.7.8 and it's not included!

Answer (score 0):

> Note The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited.

"Large" in this case is vague, but it tends to mean multiple megabytes, if not far more. The output of `rpm -qi` for a single RPM should be nowhere near that size. I wouldn't worry about efficiency here.

Apart from that, there's no need to build the command line as a single string just to split it again. Build a list to start:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['rpm', '-qi', rpm, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

---

To avoid building a large in-memory list of all RPMs (that match `stuff`), make `getrpms()` a generator instead.  That way, you don't have to read all the lines of text from the subprocess at once; you can read and process a line at a time.

```
def getrpms():
    rpmqa = subprocess.Popen(['rpm', '-qa'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'stuff'], stdin=rpmqa.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    sort = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-r'], stdin=grep.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)

    for line in sort.stdout:
        yield line
```

Comment: Ok. I don't think that the , rpm, will work in the command. It's a string. I have to pass it through .format.

Comment: Assuming `rpm` is just the name of a package, there is no need to use `format`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. rpm is the name of every package in `for rpm in getrpms():` getrpm() gets all the rpms!

BTW the output file will be 5MB of text.